# Button and String incompatibility from an Array in AS3

Tags: arrays, string, actionscript-3, button

So I have an inventory with items and the array has the instance name of the items, which are movieclips. I want to make it so that all the items will have their button mode become true.

Everything works up to i.buttonMode = true. I get this:1119: Access of possibly undefined property buttonMode through a reference with static type String. But if I use the instance name, something like Inv_1.buttonMode = true works.

So the main question is I guess, how can you iterate through an array and make each of the instance names into buttons?

(I also tried getChildByName.(i).buttonMode = true;) and that didn't work. :S

```
package  {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public dynamic class Drag extends MovieClip {
    var Inventory:Array =  ["Inv_1", "Inv_2", "Inv_3", "Inv_4t", "Inv_5"]; 

    public function Drag():void {
        for (var i:String in Inventory){ 
            i.buttonMode = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your `Inventory` array is a collection of strings, not MovieClips.

If those are instance names of child display objects, implement `getChildByName` as a function, not dot notation.

Also note `getChildByName` returns `DisplayObject`, which does not define `buttonMode`.  Cast the object as `MovieClip` or appropriate type.

```
package  {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public dynamic class Drag extends MovieClip {
    var Inventory:Array =  ["Inv_1", "Inv_2", "Inv_3", "Inv_4t", "Inv_5"]; 

    public function Drag():void {
        for (var i:String in Inventory) {
            MovieClip(getChildByName(i)).buttonMode = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i tried that too before but i got this as an error message: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property buttonMode through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: the string names in the array are the same as the instance names for my movie clip objects would that be a problem? it works if i just put: Inv_1.buttonMode = true.

Comment: getChildByName returns a DisplayObject - you need to cast it as a MovieClip.

Answer (score 1):

you have created an array of strings, not movie clip instances.

declare your instance names and add them to a vector:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public dynamic class Drag extends MovieClip
    {
        private var Inv_1:MovieClip;
        private var Inv_2:MovieClip;
        private var Inv_3:MovieClip;
        private var Inv_4:MovieClip;
        private var Inv_5:MovieClip;

        public function Drag():void
        {
            var Inventory:Vector.<MovieClip> = new <MovieClip>[Inv_1, Inv_2, Inv_3, Inv_4t, Inv_5]; 

            for (var i:MovieClip in Inventory)
            { 
                i.buttonMode = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoops - sorry about the edit.  I thought I had "you're created".  This implementation is cleaner than strings - I'd definitely recommend this approach.

Comment: thanks for the pointers! I implemented this but I got these 2 errors:1067: 

Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type flash.display:MovieClip.

1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type __AS3__.vec:Vector.<flash.display:MovieClip>.

does that have to do with how I implemented my objects before? thanks a lot!

Comment: almost working i just have 1 error now at the for loop, it says: 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type flash.display:MovieClip.

Comment: this means that either your iteration type is a string instead of a movieclip or that your vector items are strings instead of movieclips.